# Using POSIX semaphores inside of glibc's malloc

Tags: linux, makefile, pthreads, reverse-engineering, glibc

I would like to modify glibc's malloc function for some reverse engineering work and it would be incredibly handy to use POSIX semaphores for the task. The problem is that I don't know how to correctly link pthread in glibc's build process. It would be really helpful if somebody could provide links where the build process is explained in more detail than in the reference manual or help me with this issue.

Comment: You would have to implement semaphores using systems calls instead of pthread, since pthread may use malloc it self. Check implementation of [musl-libc](https://www.musl-libc.org/) or [newlib](https://sourceware.org/newlib/)

Comment: In this particular case it does. Thank you. Do you maybe know a more general approach to link libraries which don't use malloc?

Comment: General approach - lmy_lib_no_malloc for GCC :) Linking is a way for combine all object files into executable file with the required binary format, i.e. ELF32/64, PE, COFF etc. Static library is just an archive (zip file) with object files, shared library (or DLL) is the same thing like executable file, but without executable entry point. So when you are linking - you just combining object files and libraries together into executable file.

Comment: I meant a general approach to how to add a specific library to glibc's build process not how to link libraries with the compiler.

Comment: As I wrote - no any standard approaches exist, you just needs to build a lib or executable (compiler it self is just a program), everything is up to you. For example glibc uses additional lib unwind  when msul or newlib don't. In any case it is considered that C standard library (MS CRT, glibc, msul, dietlibc etc) is not depending on any another libraries. C library is a standardized interface between OS or hardware if you are writing an OS. If you about to rework/extend glibc you can start with this book: "Richard M. Stallman - Using the GNU Compiler Collection"

Answer (score 0):

The POSIX semaphores are also implemented by glibc itself, so aren't used by internal glibc functions like `malloc()` (that is: glibc *is* the pthreads implementation library).

Instead, internal glibc functions use mutex and rwlock style locks defined by [`libc-lock.h`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/generic/libc-lock.h;h=4f21f9c8c05ed5a6f1480c9da103587f6e6339ae;hb=HEAD).  You should be able to create the semaphore-style semantics you need from these building blocks.